# How can I compare 2 result

Tags: postgresql

I want to compare 2 results.

I want to check if there is a difference between predicate = 'description' and predicate = '#shortDescription' (to avoid duplicates especially).

here is my ddl (I did not manage to declare the variable). https://dbfiddle.uk/o7cHpbBl

I don't understand why the except doesn't work when I applied the same logic as [here](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-random-range/)

thank you

Comment: Please put all relevant code inline into the question.

Comment: Your code is not working. see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tH8SbPnq) with a working code. And the result of the query with `except` sounds like logic.

Comment: OK thanks a lot. I already wanted to understand why I couldn't arrive with the except => my need is the full join (instead of except) => My need is to check that shortDescription  and description are not identical (even if shortDescription or description  is null)

Comment: I probably misspoke, it's the content that I want to be unique. In other words for the url5 description should return me null because the object is identical in description and short description